# How to get time from this xml tag?

Tags: python, xml

From a [long xml document](http://waterservices.usgs.gov/nwis/iv/?format=waterml,1.1&sites=01646500&parameterCd=00060,00065) I am attempting to get just a few attributes. Specifically I am looking to get the stage cfs and ft levels, which this code accomplishes reliably. The difficulty is I cannot seem to figure out how to extract the timestamp as a datetime value from the tag similar to:

```
<ns1:value qualifiers="P" dateTime="2012-11-01T18:45:00.000-05:00">54800</ns1:value>
```

Any help and suggestions for improvement are greatly appreciated.

```
def getLevels(gaugeId):

    # create url string 00060=cfs and 00065=ft
    urlRoot = "http://waterservices.usgs.gov/nwis/iv/?format=waterml,1.1&sites="
    urlTail = "&parameterCd=00060,00065"
    url = urlRoot + str(gaugeId) + urlTail
    del urlRoot, urlTail

    # open connection to url
    urlFile = urllib2.urlopen(url)

    # convert urlFile to string data:
    urlData = urlFile.read()

    # close file to release memory
    urlFile.close()

    # parse downloaded xml
    domData = parseString(urlData)

    # extract xml element values for stage cfs and ft
    index = 0
    elementCount = domData.getElementsByTagName("ns1:value").length
    output = []
    while elementCount >= index:
        xmlString = domData.getElementsByTagName("ns1:value")[index].toxml()
        output.append(stripXmlTags(xmlString))
        index = index + 1

    # extract and return
    return output
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iter() method of ElementTree also is handy for getting some of the data that you want, as in the following.  Some example output follows the program.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from xml.etree import cElementTree as ET
from datetime import datetime
import re

with open('waterservices.usgs.gov.xml','r') as fi:
    waterData = ''.join(fi.readlines())
waterData = re.sub('ns[12]:', '', waterData)
root = ET.fromstring(waterData)
dates = [v.get('dateTime') for v in root.iter('value')]
valus = [float(v.text) for v in root.iter('value')]
units = [v.text for v in root.iter('variableName')]
print 'valus', valus
print 'units', units
print 'dates', dates
dates = [datetime.strptime(t[:-6], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f') for t in dates]
print 'dates', dates
a = zip (valus, units, dates)
for v in a:
    print v
```

(Note, I don't know how to correctly handle the prefixes `ns1:` and `ns2:`, so in the above have suppressed them via `re.sub`.  Data was taken from a file for brevity in the above demo code instead of retaining `urllib2` code. Also, as in an earlier answer, time zone isn't handled.)  The  example output below is based on XML data file at
[link from question](http://waterservices.usgs.gov/nwis/iv/?format=waterml,1.1&sites=01646500&parameterCd=00060,00065), saved as a local file `waterservices.usgs.gov.xml`.

```
valus [53200.0, 6.86]
units ['Streamflow, ft&#179;/s', 'Gage height, ft']
dates ['2012-11-01T19:45:00.000-05:00', '2012-11-01T19:45:00.000-05:00']
dates [datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 1, 19, 45), datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 1, 19, 45)]
(53200.0, 'Streamflow, ft&#179;/s', datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 1, 19, 45))
(6.86, 'Gage height, ft', datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 1, 19, 45))
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use this as a starting point - note this currently ignores the timezone...

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.fromstring(urlData)
for elem in tree.findall('.//{http://www.cuahsi.org/waterML/1.1/}value'):
    print datetime.strptime(elem.attrib['dateTime'][:-10], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
```